# Julia: Error when trying to minimize a function with optimize

Tags: optimization, julia

I have the following function with multiple arguments that I would like to minimize with Optim.jl:

```
function post(parm,y,x,n)
  # Evaluate the log of the marginal posterior for parm at a point

  fgamma=zeros(n,1);
  for ii = 1:2
    fgamma = fgamma + parm[ii+1]*(x[:,ii+1].^parm[4]);
  end

  fgamma = fgamma.^(1/parm[4]);
  fgamma = fgamma + parm[1]*ones(n,1);

  lpost = .5*n*log.((y - fgamma)'*(y-fgamma));
end
```

However, when i try to use `optimize`, Julia returns an error.

Old error (with parm):

```
MethodError: no method matching finite_difference!(::##1#2, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Symbol)
```

New error(with parm2):

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,2} to an object of type Float64
```

The complete script with data and optimize call I am using is this:

```
using Distributions
using Optim

n = 200;
k = 3;
x = ones(n,k);
fgamma=zeros(n,1);
gam = [1.01; 0.6; 0.8; 1.5];
x[:,2] = rand(Chisq(10),n);
x[:,3] = rand(Chisq(5),n);
epsl = rand(Normal(0,1),n);
y = zeros(n,1);

for i = 1:n
    y[i,1] = gam[1] + (gam[2]*x[i,2]^gam[4] + gam[3]*x[i,3]^gam[4])^(1/gam[4]) + epsl[i];
end

# Sim
bols = inv(x'x)x'y;
s2 = (y-x*bols)'*(y-x*bols)/(n-k);
sse=(n-k)*s2;
bolscov = s2.*inv(x'*x);
bolssd=zeros(k,1);
for i = 1:k
  bolssd[i,1]=sqrt(bolscov[i,i]);
end

# Calculate posterior mode and Hessian at mode
nparam=k+1;
parm = ones(nparam,1);
parm[1:k,1]=bols;
parm2 = vec(parm);

opt = Optim.Options(f_tol = 1e-8, iterations = 1000);
Optim.after_while!{T}(d, state::Optim.BFGSState{T}, method::BFGS, options) = global invH = state.invH

res = optimize(p -> post(p,y,x,n), parm2, BFGS(), opt)
```

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong? I think that the there is a problem with the type of `lpost` in the function `post`, since it returns a 1x1 Array{Float64,2}. Unfortunately, i couldn't handle it well.

Comment: Do you have an old version of Calculus.jl? Check `Pkg.status()`

Comment: I have Calculus version 0.2.2, Optim version 0.9.3 and Julia v0.6.

Comment: Have you tried adding `return lpost[1,1]` as the last line of `post` function?

Comment: Thank you, @DanGetz. This is a good and simple solution. I also had to change  `fgamma = fgamma.^(1/parm[4]);` for `fgamma = fgamma.^Complex(1/parm[4]);` and `return real(lpost[1,1])` as the last line of `post` function, because of a `DomainError`.

Comment: @fst Cool, I've written this up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,2} to an object of type Float64
```

is caused by an attempt to convert a matrix into a scalar. In general this is not possible, but when the matrix is a 1x1 matrix (as the question pointed out), there is a natural transformation: `scalar = matrix[1,1]`.

`optimize` wants a scalar value returned because it is a *scalar non-linear optimization routine*. Optimizing a vector value is even hard to unambiguously define (concepts such as Pareto optima is an attempt to do so).

So, after this prelude, the fix is simple, together with an issue with Complex optimization @fst (the poster) later tackled. Again, a single dimensional scalar is required, so `real(...)` was used to make a scalar out of a complex value (more precisely an *ordered* scalar, as complex numbers are scalars too). The resulting `post` function is:

```
function post(parm,y,x,n)
  # Evaluate the log of the marginal posterior for parm at a point

  fgamma=zeros(n,1);
  for ii = 1:2
    fgamma = fgamma + parm[ii+1]*(x[:,ii+1].^parm[4]);
  end

  fgamma = fgamma.^Complex(1/parm[4]);
  fgamma = fgamma + parm[1]*ones(n,1);

  lpost = .5*n*log.((y - fgamma)'*(y-fgamma));
  return real(lpost[1,1])
end
```